# How do I change INNODB_PAGE_SIZE in mysql existing database

Tags: mysql, innodb, alter-table

Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB or using ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC or ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED may help. In current row format, BLOB prefix of 768 bytes is stored inline

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. What exactly is the problem you have or what are you trying to do?

Comment: What version of MySQL?  (There have been changes.)  Let's look at the specific table in trouble, there may be a much simpler solution.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.